# This code doesnot print tom in the browser

Tags: constructor

```
function Dog(name, class, breed) {
this.name = name;
this.class = class;
this.breed = breed;
}

var harry= new Dog("harry", 15, "indian");
var tom = new Dog("tom", 16, "american");

document.write(tom.name);
```

This does not print tom in the browser.. why?????

Comment: Well, what *does* it do? If it results in a syntax error or whatnot, well *stop and fix it* (searching for the error message as necessary) before trying to continue with a meaningful dialog about the behavior of non-executing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is a reserved word, so you can't use it as a property name. You can change it to some other name, e.g. `Class` to overcome the issue.

```
    function Dog(name, Class, breed) {
this.name = name;
this.Class = Class;
this.breed = breed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because you used the word `class`, however `class` is a reserved word. So replace `class` with something else. This is how your code should look like. I replaced `class` with cls

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Dog(name, cls, breed) {
this.name = name;
this.cls = cls;
this.breed = breed;
}

var harry= new Dog("harry", 15, "indian");
var tom = new Dog("tom", 16, "american");
document.write(tom.name);
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```